# Blank White page issue in WordPress

Tags: permissions, debug

I am working in a WordPress site in Linux Mint. My file and folder permission is like below

[image]

I used below code in `wp-config.php` file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );

@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

But I am getting blank white page in WordPress Home page.

I checked `wp-content` folder for `debug.log`, but there is no `debug.log` file. I checked `apache 2` `error.log` file, but it is empty.

What is the solution ?

Comment: See my answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357214/error-logs-to-diagnose-error-500-in-lamp/357237#357237 regarding debug logs. You need to specify a path for the debug log file. Also your file/folder permissions are incorrect. If this is a production site folders should be 755 and files 644. This script can be used to set your permissions for Wordpress usage (https://gist.github.com/macbleser/9136424).

Comment: Thanks @AdmiralNoisyBottom

Comment: I hope it helps you track down your issue.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom. This is my new file/folder permissions. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SDO3.png. I tried several ways but could not come out from White Blank page issue.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom. I am not so expert about file/folder permissions. Could you please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Download the script I mentioned earlier and put it into your Wordpress folder. You need to edit the script and change the WP_OWNER, WP_GROUP to www-data. Then change the WP_ROOT to path for your wordpress and WS_GROUP to www-data then save it. In a terminal window (right click & select Terminal) and type chmod +x wp-permissions-script.sh or whatever you called the script, then type ./wp-permissions-script.sh. From memory that's it.

Comment: Here is another tutorial that might help you regarding file permissions. https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks @AdmiralNoisyBottom. After following your suggestion my permission is like below  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKrPI.png. White page issues is not solved. Thanks.

Comment: I knew the permissions wouldn't fix your original problem, but it was worth fixing. Does the debug log give you any further information. Also, change your theme to the default and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Thanks @AdmiralNoisyBottom. This is a Theme issue not permission issue. Thanks.